# How do I write mongo aggregation reduce query in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

data in mongo :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB92w.jpg)

```
db.test2.aggregate([
    {
        "$project" : {
        "contents" : 1,
        "comments" : {
            "$filter" : {
                "input" : "$comments", 
                "as" : "item", 
                "cond" : {"$gt" : ['$$item.score', 2]}

                },
            },
         "comments2" : {
            "$filter" : {
                "input" : "$comments2", 
                "as" : "item", 
                "cond" : {"$gt" : ["$$item.score", 5]}
            }
            }
        }
     },
     {
     "$project" : {
            "content" : 1,
            "commentsTotal" : {
                "$reduce" : {
                    "input" : "$comments",
                    "initialValue" : 0,
                    "in" : {"$add" : ["$$value", "$$this.score"]}
                }
                },
            "comments2Total" : {
                "$reduce" : {
                "input" : "$comments2",
                "initialValue" : 0,
                    "in" : {"$add" : ["$$value", "$$this.score"]}
                }
            }
        }
      },
      {$skip : 0},
      {$limit: 3}

  ]);
  <!-- language: lang-json-->
```

So you can see, this does the following : 
1、filter the comments and comments2 which score is gt 5.
2、count total of the socre in comment array.

and i write the aggregation query in Spring like this:

```java
AggregationExpression reduce = ArithmeticOperators.Add.valueOf("$$value").add("$$this.socre");
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.project().andExclude("_id")
                    .andInclude("content")
                    .and("comments").filter("item", ComparisonOperators.Gt.valueOf("item.score").greaterThanValue(3)).as("comments")
                    .and("comments2").filter("item", ComparisonOperators.Gt.valueOf("item.score").greaterThanValue(3)).as("comments2"),
            Aggregation.project("comments", "comments2")
                    .and(ArrayOperators.Reduce.arrayOf("comments").withInitialValue("0").reduce(reduce)).as("commentsTotal")
    );
```

when i run like up , it will throws exception :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference '$$value'!

Comment: Looks like two project stage is causing this behavior.  We can easily workaround this issue if you just need the count as final output as shown in your shell query.

Comment: how can i do now ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try below aggregation by wrapping `$filter` inside the `$reduce` operation.

Something like below

```
AggregationExpression reduce1 = new AggregationExpression() {
        @Override
        public DBObject toDbObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
         DBObject filter = new BasicDBObject("$filter", new BasicDBObject("input", "$comments").append("as", "item").append("cond",
                    new BasicDBObject("$gt", Arrays.<Object>asList("$$item.score", 2))));
         DBObject reduce = new BasicDBObject("input", filter).append("initialValue", 0).append("in", new BasicDBObject("$add", Arrays.asList("$$value", "$$this.socre")));
         return new BasicDBObject("$reduce", reduce);
     }
 };

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
     Aggregation.project().andExclude("_id")
       .andInclude("content")
       .and(reduce1).as("commentsTotal")
);
```

Comment: I try like this :

AggregationExpression reduce = ArithmeticOperators.Add.valueOf("$$value").add("$$this.socre");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
  Aggregation.project()
    .andInclude("content")
    .and(ArrayOperators.Reduce.arrayOf(
      ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("comments").as("item").by(ComparisonOperators.Gt.valueOf("item.score").greaterThanValue(2))).
      withInitialValue(0).reduce(reduce)).as("commentsTotal")
);

Comment: exception :
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Command execution failed:  Error [Use of undefined variable: value], Command = { "aggregate" : "test2" , "pipeline" : [ { "$project" : { "content" : 1 , "commentsTotal" : { "$reduce" : { "input" : { "$add" : [ "$$value" , "$$this.socre"]} , "initialValue" : 0 , "in" : { "$add" : [ "$$value" , "$$this.socre"]}}}}}]}; nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "git.ivymei.com:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "Use of undefined variable: value" , "code" : 17276 , "codeName" : "Location17276"}

Comment: Sorry, it looks like the chaining aggregation operators is not working as expected. I have replaced with the another solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but in case some one winds up here like me, here's how I was able to solve it.

You cannot access "**$$this**" and "**$$value**" variables directly like this in spring.

```
AggregationExpression reduce = ArithmeticOperators.Add.valueOf("$$value").add("$$this.socre");
```

To do this we have to use reduce variable enum, like this:

```
AggregationExpression reduce = ArithmeticOperators.Add.valueOf(ArrayOperators.Reduce.Variable.VALUE.getTarget()).add(ArrayOperators.Reduce.Variable.THIS.referringTo("score").getTarget());
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve next task and hadn't find any solutions. So i hope my answer will help somebody.

User with roles (user have list of rights + list of roles, each role have own list of rights, needed to find full list of rights):

[user structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOX2J.png)

[role structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxeNY.png)

First, i lookup roles to roleDto (for example), then i collect rights from roles to 1 list:

```
ArrayOperators.Reduce reduce = ArrayOperators.Reduce.arrayOf("$roleDto.rights")
        .withInitialValue(new ArrayList<>())
        .reduce(ArrayOperators.ConcatArrays.arrayOf("$$value").concat("$$this"));
```

As result in reduce i have this 1 list of rights collected from roles.
After that i make:

```
SetOperators.SetUnion.arrayAsSet(reduce).union("$rights")
```

using previous result. Result type is AggregationExpression because AbstractAggregationExpression implements AggregationExpression.

So, finally i get smth like this (sorry for messy code):

```
private static AggregationExpression getAllRightsForUser() {
    // concat rights from list of roles (each role have list of rights) - list of list to list
    ArrayOperators.Reduce reduce = ArrayOperators.Reduce.arrayOf("$roleDto.rights")
        .withInitialValue(new ArrayList<>())
        .reduce(ArrayOperators.ConcatArrays.arrayOf("$$value").concat("$$this"));
    // union result with user.rights
    return SetOperators.SetUnion.arrayAsSet(reduce).union("$rights");
}
```

Result of this operation can be finally used somewhere like here ;) :

```
public static AggregationOperation addFieldOperation(AggregationExpression aggregationExpression, String fieldName) {
    return aoc -> new Document("$addFields", new Document(fieldName, aggregationExpression.toDocument(aoc)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, one of the solutions is to create a custom Reduce function, here's Union example:

```
public class SetUnionReduceExpression implements AggregationExpression {
    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new Document("$setUnion", ImmutableList.of("$$value", "$$this"));
    }
}
```